# Can I allocate and evaluate an expression within loop while?

Tags: c, while-loop, expression, variable-assignment

I mean something like that:

```
while(lu = read(d1, buf, sizeof(buf)), lu > 0 )
```

it's good syntax ?

Comment: Ask your compiler, if it is. Ask your colleagues, if you want to know if it's good style. I don't think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good syntax, but very bad semantics.

In other words, that code doesn't do what you think it does, which makes it a bit dangerous.

Since assignment (`=`) has lower priority than comparison (`>`), it will not evaluate in the way you need.

To fix it, add parentheses:

```
while((lu = read(d1, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0)
```

Also, remember that `sizeof` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
while((lu = read(d1, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0 )
```